# Adding Buy Button to Blog Post (Woocommerce)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, blog

I'm using Woocommerce. Is it possible to add a buy button to a blog post that features a specific product? Can it be added to a blog post with a shortcode perhaps (so that it’s easily do-able by the client)?

We’ll publish a blog post about a product, add some videos, images and text, and then include a buy button. The buy button should add the specific product to the cart.

If it isn’t possible at all, any recommendations on how to implement this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possibly this? http://www.johnbhartley.com/2014/adding-buy-now-button-woocommerce/

Comment: Nice! Sorry I'm lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WooCommerce by default supports shortcodes that can be embedded in a post, one of those is a 'Add to Cart' shortcode.

See the WooCommerce documentation at https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/